# How does escape character work in bash quote?

Tags: bash, escaping

Reading through [Escape Character](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character) and [Quotes sections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes)

For escape character "", It mentions that

> It preserves the literal value of the next character that follows

For sigle quote

> ' preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes

```
echo 'a\\nb'
> a\nb
echo 'a\\\nb'
> a\
> b
```

**Questions are:**

1. Why \ is not interpretated as its literal meaning, instead **2 backslash** is interpretated as one \ here ?

2.1 Are all the sequence in [ANSI c standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences) reserved as a single character ?

2.2 But following example seems contradicating to the above assumption.

```
echo '\"'
> \"  # instead of printing ", it prints \"
```

Comment: are you using `zsh` instead of `bash` by any chance ? I have a different behaviour  different between the 2 shells

Comment: @Aserre, thx, Aserre, it turns out I am using zsh, which have different behavior.

Comment: Some versions of `echo` do their own escape (backslash) interpretation, which complicates matters a great deal. Use `printf '%s\n' 'a\\nb'` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI escape sequences are interpreted by the shell, only if you wrap them around `$'..'` and not otherwise

In the case of `'a\\nb'` without the ANSI sequences, it is treated literally as characters `a`, followed by two `\`, `n` and `b`. Only within the ANSI quoting syntax it is treated special, i.e. in `$'a\\nb'`, the `\n` is interpreted as special sequence for a newline character, but that expansion is deferred because of the additional escape which prevents the `\n` from being expanded, making it expanded literally.

```
echo 'a\\nb'
a\\nb
echo $'a\\nb'
a\nb
```

The case of `'a\\\nb'` is the same, without the ANSI escapes, the content is expanded literally, but with the presence of quotes, the sequence `a\\\nb` is interpreted by the shell to be having one escape character for `\` as `\\` and one `\n`, so it expands to

```
echo $'a\\\nb'
a\
b
```

Yes, the ANSI escape sequences are treated as a single character when the shell expands it.

And there is no escape sequence expansion involved in `'\"'`, with the presence of single quotes the content within is preserved literally

```
echo '\"'
\"
echo '"'
"
```

Note that with ANSI quoting for the above case the `$'..'` is expanded, expanding any potential escape sequences, so  `\"` expands to just `"`

```
echo $'\"'
"
```

Reference - [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

Comment: thx @inian for the detailed explanation, turns out I am using zsh as my default shell, thus the output is not working as expected.

Comment: The quotes or escapes are not ANSI. The C standard which specifies this kind of quoting is an ANSI standard. The naming here is quite unfortunate, especially because there is such a thing as ANSI escape sequences (what you would use in the old days to produce color in terminals).

Comment: @sthbuilder Probably just accept one of the answers here and move on. You *asked* about Bash, they answered about Bash. You can't change the question to be about zsh now.

Answer (score 0):

Between the `' '` quotes there is no interpretation of escape sequences. Write

```
"\""
```

and you get the expected behavior.